# Isn’t "higher-priced products" with an adjective ungrammatical for the correct "more highly priced products" with an adverb?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, compounds, flat-adverbs, zero-derivation

The phrase *higher-priced products* is very common, but isn’t it grammatically incorrect?

The adjective *higher* is being forced to servce as an adverb here, so the phrase should instead be *more highly priced*.

What’s the verdict?

Comment: If your analysis fails to account for what people actually say, then your analysis is at fault, and should be discarded or improved.

Comment: And that's because what people actually do and say is always correct?

Comment: "Correct" is a social judgment. I am not interested in fashion. If people say it, it's what the language - at least their variety of it - is.

Comment: But this argument isn't considered when appraising academic works or school exams, for instance. Aren't you considering even a little that when people ask here what is grammatically correct they have these aspects in mind?

Comment: There are plenty of internet examples of the open ('higher priced') and hyphenated ('higher-priced') forms. [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/high-priced) gives the positive form _high-priced_; while this doesn't licence the comparative form, it shows that _using an [apparent] adjective as the first element in a compound adjective_ isn't 'ungrammatical' per se. Here are more examples: part-time / blue-eyed / cold-blooded / open-minded / brand-new / cross-party / full-bodied / lower-class / free-standing / rational- minded / like-minded / narrow-mouthed /widemouthed ....

Comment: What people actually do isn't always correct, but in this case you yourself said the expression is very common, so it would seem that it is accepted as normal by a significant fraction of English speakers. Doesn't that make it a part of the English language and thus correct? English isn't like maths, in which generally a given problem can have only one correct answer whether most people agree with it or not, the English language is governed by a committee comprising all English speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Both are correct** with long-established usage. You can say "more [highly](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/highly)" if you like, but according to [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/high):

> *adverb*, **high·er**, **high·est**.
>
> - at or to a high point, place, or level.
> - in or to a high rank or estimate: He aims high in his political ambitions.

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=high) agrees:

> *adv.* **higher**, **highest**
>
> 1. At, in, or to a lofty position, level, or degree: *saw a plane flying high in the sky; prices that had gone too high.*
> 2. In an extravagant or luxurious way: *made a fortune and lived high.*

See also:

- [Highly etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/highly)
- [High etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/high)

Comment: But there does not need to be an accepted adverbial usage for the first element of a compound adjective. Blue-eyed, blue-green, cold-blooded, absent-minded. A noun may 'be the first element': ice-cold.

Comment: In this case there *is* an accepted adverbial usage, so it doesn't matter whether there *needs* to be one.

Comment: That argues that an adverb may always be used to modify an adjective if it fits semantically. 'Short priced favourite' is common, whereas 'shortly priced favourite' is unidiomatic.

Answer (score -2):

## *Aiming high, jumping higher, and climbing highest*

A word does not have to end in *-ly* to be an adverb, you know. Examplars include *soon, thus, early, late, often, always, low, high, fast, slow, deep, more, well*, not to mention *sooner, better, less, earliest, slower, most, highest, later, least, worse, best, worst, deeper, fastest* and all the many, **many** others just like all of those.

I’m afraid that this is a case of what we call [***hypercorrection***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection), which per the Wikipedia link given means:

> non-standard use of language that results from the over-application of a perceived rule of language-usage prescription.

That’s because the word *high* is now — and ever has been — a super-common and perfectly fine adverb in the English language.

### Documentation

The OED entry for the adverb *high* details no fewer than **77 different senses** (comprising 19 main senses and 58 subentry senses) along with 466 citations, many dating from Old English itself more than a millennium ago, and with many stretching all the way into our current decade as I write this.

Here are just a scant few of those 77 senses:

> 1. a. To or into a high place, position, or point; so as to be high or tall.
>
>    b. In a high position; at a high altitude; far up, aloft.
>
>    c. Esp. with reference to the movement or gait of a horse: with the feet lifted relatively high above the ground. Cf. low adv. 1c.
>
>    d. Far up towards the source (of a river).
> 2. In or into a high latitude on the earth's surface; far from the equator.
> 3. c. figurative. Towards or at a lofty or ambitious goal. Frequently in to aim high (cf. to aim high at aim v. 5a(b)).
> 4. c. At a high rate, amount, or price.
>
>    d. Richly, luxuriously; to excess. Now chiefly in to live high; cf. to live high on the hog at hog n.1
> 5. With reference to music or song: at a high pitch; in or to a high note or range of notes.

That doesn’t even count the many senses for the **comparative adverb** *higher* and the **superlative adverb** *highest*. Those too have been part of English since Old English, back when the years were numbered using three digits alone. Here, though, are a few of the many splendid citations more recent than the Norman Conquest provided there, with the word in question here rendered in boldface which the OED uses an underline for:

> - 1913   J. Muir *Story my Boyhood* i. 18  
>    We tried to see who could climb **highest** on the crumbling peaks and crags.
> - 1961   F. C. Avis Sportsman's Gloss. 111/2 
>     Beamer, a ball aimed **high** by the bowler, often to the height of the batsman's head.
> - 1972   D. McCulloch *Great Bridge* xxi. 474 
>     It would be ‘her remarkable talent as a peacemaker’..that he would praise **highest**.
> - a1979   N. Ray *I was Interrupted* (1993) 100 
>     Lines went haywire, actions went haywire, Arthur got thrown **higher** than a kite.
> - 1992   *Independent* 4 Aug. 12/3 
>     What are the implications of this for women aiming **high**? Must they be better, more hard-working than the men? Must they play office politics?
> - 1998   A. Taylor *Suffocating Night* (2003) ix. 64 
>     Howard waited and watched as the sun climbed **higher** in the sky.
> - 2008   *N.Y. Times* (National ed.) 7 Oct. f11/5 
>     Typically, break fees are about 3 percent of the deal value, but they are creeping **higher**.
> - 2010   E. Verhagen in D. J. Caina et al. Epidemiol. Injury in Olympic Sports xxiii. 330/1 
>     Biomechanical studies have revealed an increased incidence in jumper's knee among those athletes who jump **highest**.
> - 2011   R. Clements *Revenger* vii. 47 
>     It was drawn by four white stallions, all proudly harnessed with feathers and shields, their forelegs trotting **high** and in time.

Those are all perfectly fine adverbs, as I’m sure you’ll agree.

## Summary

Therefore, returning to your original example with all this in mind, when one product has been given a **higher price** because it has been **priced higher** than another one is, then that first product is certainly the higher-priced product of the two.

Comment: @xiota How does that make this not a case of hypercorrection? To be clear, the answer is saying that the hypercorrection is believing _higher-priced_ to be incorrect because _higher_ does not end in _-ly_ and thus cannot be an adverb. That is indeed a form of hypercorrection, although a less common form than most hypercorrections.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet This answer states that hypercorrection is "non-standard use of language that results from the over-application of a perceived rule of language-usage prescription." – since *high, higher, highest,* and *highly* have long-established, standard usage as adverbs, this does not fit *that* definition of hypercorrection.